# Exclude Random Redirect from caching?

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache, server-load

- I have just deployed [the W3 Total Cache plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) on my dedicated server (`moillusions.com`), but am not sure if it works already (server load still high).
- I have a very important [random link generator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/random-redirect/): `moillusions.com/?random`. Yet I am not sure how to exclude this from caching? (so it's always a different link when clicked)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery or Javascript to cycle through and randomly pick one of your links, this way you can bypass the caching?

```
var messages = ["Good!", "Great!", "Awesome!", "Super!", "Nice!"];
function getMessage() {
   return messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
}
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419928/how-can-i-return-a-random-value-from-an-array

Answer (score 0):

1. What this plugin is supposed to do about server load, if anything?
2. This depends on caching setup you use, good caching plugins try to intelligently skip obviously dynamic pages with query arguments in URL.

Comment: sorry, thought it's w3 total cache help forum (mistake)

Comment: anyone knows how to disable the url.com?random from caching with w3 total cache?

Comment: @vurdlak make sure that _Performance > Page Cache > General > Cache URIs with query string variables_ is not checked. Although I don't see how this matters since that performs redirect to post which can be cached just fine, has little to do with how user got there.

Comment: hi, this is because when I click moillusions.com?random it brings me to a page, and when I'm over reading it, click it again, but brings me to same page (as ?random is cached to same page). let me try this what you said

Comment: @Rarst.. this is unchecked by default, yet random doesn't refresh to new page when clicked again (always brings to same page)

Comment: @vurdlak yep, redirect header does seem to stay same... I am not sure about this, you might be better of contacting W3TC developer

Comment: ok, w3 guys are on it, let's see if they can help